# Помогите с функцией в си

Tags: c

Дана функция с меню и массив строк. Задача: пользователь вводит с клавиатуры нужную ему цифру и переходит в следующее меню.  Никак не могу понять, как привязать массив строк и использовать его в своей функции.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
char str_array [6];
str_array [0] = "1";
str_array [1] = "2";
str_array [2] = "3";
str_array [3] = "4";
str_array [4] = "5";
str_array [5] = "6";

menu();


return 0;
}

void menu (char *str_array []){
    printf("+------------------------------------------------------------ 
------------------------------------------------------+\n");
    printf("|                                              MENU                                                                
|\n");
    printf("+------------------------------------------------------------ 
------------------------------------------------------+ \n");
    printf("|1) Enter Data                                                                                                     
    | \n");
    printf("+------------------------------------------------------------ 
    ------------------------------------------------------+ \n");
    printf("|2) Output Data                                                                                                    
     | \n");
    printf("+------------------------------------------------------------ 
     ------------------------------------------------------+ \n");
    printf("|3) Display the year in which the minimum temperature was 
     reached                                                  | \n");
    printf("+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+ \n");
    printf("|4) Output the number of days of the specified year in which the cloud cover did not exceed the specified number %% | \n");
    printf("+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+ \n");
    printf("|5) Output the average air temperature for the specified day (all years).                                          | \n");
    printf("+------------------------------------------------------------ 
     ------------------------------------------------------+ \n");
    printf("|6) Exit                                                                                                           
    | \n");
    printf("+------------------------------------------------------------ 
     ------------------------------------------------------+ \n");


       }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int menu(const char **items)
{
    int items_count = 0, answer = 0;

    for (const char **item = items; *item; item++, items_count++)
        printf("%d->%s\n", items_count + 1, *item);

    while (1)
    {
        printf("Make a choice: ");

        if (scanf("%d", &answer) < 1)
            scanf("%*[^\n]");
        if (answer > 0 && answer <= items_count)
            break;
        puts("Wrong data!");
    }       
    return answer - 1;
}

int main(void)
{
    const char *items[] = {"Enter data", "Output data", "Display", "Other", 
NULL};
    int res;

    res = menu(items);
    printf("In \"%s\" seq\n", items[res]);

    return 0;
}
```